# Other application of Liouville's theorem besides thermodynamics

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Are there any other important practical and theoretical consequences of [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29) on the conservation of phase space volume besides the calculation of the microcanonical potential in Thermodynamics?

Answer (score 3):

1) On a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29#Symplectic_geometry) $(M,\omega)$, Liouville's theorem is often stated as that every [Hamiltonian vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_f=\{f,\cdot\}$ is divergence-free

$$ {\rm div}_{\rho} X_f~=~0 ,$$

where the volume density $\rho$ comes from the canonical volume form

$$\Omega~=~\rho dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^{2n}.$$

Here the canonical volume form

$$\Omega~:=~\omega^{\wedge n}$$

is top exterior power of the symplectic 2-form $\omega$.

Equivalently, the Lie derivative of the canonical volume form

$$ {\cal L}_{X_f}\Omega~=~0, $$

wrt. a Hamiltonian vector field, vanishes.

2) It is interesting to note that Liouville's theorem generalizes to symplectic [supermanifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold) $(M,\omega)$ with Grassmann-even symplectic structure.

3) However Liouville's theorem fails for Grassmann-odd symplectic manifolds, also known as antisymplectic manifolds, or [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism). Such manifolds do not have a canonical volume density $\rho$ either. Nevertheless, let us assume that there at least exists *some* volume density $\rho$. Then the failure of Hamiltonian vector fields to be divergence-free is measured by the odd Laplacian

$$ \Delta_{\rho} f ~=~\frac{(-1)^{|f|}}{2}{\rm div}_{\rho} X_f, $$

where $|f|$ denotes the Grassmann parity of the function $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Conservation of [étendue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) is essentially the same thing as Liouville's theorem applied to the space of rays of light in geometric optics. This is central to [non-imaging optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics), for example in the design of car headlamps or in concentrating sunlight in photovoltaic cells.

Answer (score 1):

Although I know little about this, other applications I have seen are in beam physics where one can make arguments about beam [emittance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_emittance).  In particular one can argue that emittance remains constant in certain situations, using Liouville's theorem.  See e.g. [this article](http://cds.cern.ch/record/242313/files/p89.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

This theorem is concerned with defining two parts: one is conservation of density in phase space and other is conservation of extension in phase space.